# Does selenium 'find_element' cmd activate dirver requesting something to web?

Tags: selenium, python-3.6

I guess every web site ban crawler, when crawler requests so many times in a short time.

Thus I am curious whenever activating `find_element` cmd, selenium requests response to web server?

if so, even if I got HTML code from current page and iterate it to find details using `find_element` for each css as below, I don't think prevent the web site from blocking me:

```
css = 'body > div.container.me-body-container > div.row > div.col-xs-45 > div > div > div.content-container > div.level-products'
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(css)

for item in items:
    name = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
    price = item.find_element_by_class_name('level-product-promprice').text
    order = item.find_element_by_class_name('level-product-price').text

    item_dict = dict()
    item_dict['name'] = name
    item_dict['price'] = price
    item_dict['order'] = order
    item_ls.append(item_dict)
```

Please kindly advice me to avoid bullying web servers by redundant requests:)